# To display the sum of values inside the inner tags of xml through C#

Tags: c#, xml

I have to display the total sum of Quantities of Power supply. This is the code

```
XmlNodeList quantities = xworkload.SelectNodes("//PowerSupply/Item/quantity");

int sum = 0;
foreach (XmlNode quantity in quantities) // Iterates into the quantity inner tag
{
    sum = sum + Int32.Parse(quantity.InnerText);
    MessageBox.Show("The power supply count is " + sum.ToString());
}
```

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: It is working fine, But I need to show the sum of all the quantities in a single shot, not by adding up.

Comment: then put your message box outside of your foreach loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `LINQ to XML`:

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load("path");
int sum = xDoc.Descendants("quantity").Select(x => (int)x).Sum();
MessageBox.Show("The power supply count is " + sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
XmlDocument xworkload = new XmlDocument();

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
 xworkload.Load(path to xml);
 string xmlcontents = xworkload.InnerXml;

                XmlNodeList quantities = xworkload.SelectNodes("//PowerSupply/Item/quantity");
                int sum = 0;
                foreach (XmlNode quantity in quantities)
                {
                    sum = sum + Int32.Parse(quantity.InnerText);                    
                }
    MessageBox.Show("The power supply count is " + sum.ToString());
 }
```